# Android Studio: Emulator starts but it doesn't have my application in the emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I got HAXM installed. Minimum API level is correct. Sometimes it just doesn't show my application in the app list. Sometimes it says at the start "Unfortunately Launcher3 has stopped" (still no app) I even tried to create a new blank project and tried to run that, even a blank project doesn't run. Like 2 days ago it was working, now it doesn't. I even tried to completely uninstalling, no result.

I'm getting these errors at logcat http://pastebin.com/5yBZTRGH

Comment: Same problem here after upgrading Android Studio and OSX :/